# Windows Registry access flags

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I'm having some issues with querying and modifying registry values. This code accesses the BAM in the registry and reads the subkeys and checks a vector of strings against the REG_BINARY values in the subkeys. For some reason when trying to give it "*KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE*" permissions it fails to print out the value where a string match was found, only when giving it "*KEY_READ*" flag alone will it print out.

I've tried several other flags and "*KEY_ALL_ACCESS*" for example does the same and no output is printed.

My goal is to print the value and info about its location and type, and then have it remove the value entirely. Since I'm having issues with permissions I never got to test actually removing the values, so I have no idea if RegSetValueExW does it correctly. (code never been triggered because of permissions issues)

```
    bool modifyBamRegistry() {
    HKEY hKey;
    LPCWSTR subkeyPath = L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\bam\\State\\UserSettings";

    if (RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subkeyPath, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        DWORD index = 0;
        WCHAR subkeyName[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD subkeyNameSize = MAX_PATH;

        std::vector<std::wstring> keywords = { L"test1", L"test2", L"test3" };

        while (RegEnumKeyExW(hKey, index, subkeyName, &subkeyNameSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            HKEY subkey;
            if (RegOpenKeyExW(hKey, subkeyName, 0, KEY_READ, &subkey) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                DWORD valueIndex = 0;
                WCHAR valueName[MAX_PATH];
                DWORD valueNameSize = MAX_PATH;

                while (RegEnumValueW(subkey, valueIndex, valueName, &valueNameSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                    DWORD valueType;
                    DWORD dataSize;
                    if (RegQueryValueExW(subkey, valueName, NULL, &valueType, NULL, &dataSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS &&
                        valueType == REG_BINARY && containsKeywords(valueName, keywords)) {
                        std::wcout << "Subkey: " << subkeyName << ", Value Name: " << valueName << ", Value Type: REG_BINARY" << std::endl;

                        DWORD emptyData = 0;
                        if (RegSetValueExW(subkey, valueName, 0, REG_BINARY, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&emptyData), sizeof(emptyData)) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                            std::wcout << "Deleted value: " << valueName << " from subkey: " << subkeyName << std::endl;
                        }
                        else {
                            std::wcerr << "Failed to delete value: " << valueName << " from subkey: " << subkeyName << std::endl;
                        }
                    }

                    valueIndex++;
                    valueNameSize = MAX_PATH;
                }

                RegCloseKey(subkey);
            }

            index++;
            subkeyNameSize = MAX_PATH;
        }

        RegCloseKey(hKey);

        return true;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open the registry key." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate if anyone knows why this might not be working and point me in the correct direction!

EDIT: I've tried *KEY_ALL_ACCESS* as the outer call and *KEY_WRITE | KEY_READ* as inner call. It was mentioned that the subkey was read-only for administrators, and I've tested it with *SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME* and *WRITE_OWNER* flag with no success either.

Comment: The flags control what you want to do, not if you have the right to do so. A lot of keys can only be changed with administrator privileges.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm running it as administrator and, I should have the sufficient rights to do both reading and writing.

Comment: There are two calls to `RegOpenKeyExW` in the code you show. Are you talking about the  access mask in *both* calls? Or, if only one, then which one?

Comment: By "it fails to print out the value" do you mean that the values are successfully retrieved and set, and you are executing the ``wcout <<` but nothing gets printed? Or do you mean "It fails to read the value" (so I never get to the point where I try to print it)? Or do you mean "It fails to open the key" (so I never get to the enumeration, which means I don't get to the query, which means I don't get to the `wcout <<`)?

Comment: I mean, if your *outer* call only gives `KEY_READ` access, then the *inner* call(s) with an added `KEY_WRITE` access will likely fail.

Comment: If you look at the key permissions in Regedit, you'll see that Administrators have read-only access to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\bam\State\UserSettings`.

Comment: @AdrianMole I've tried both just in case; but yeah giving *KEY_ALL_ACCESS* in the outer call and *KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE* in the inner call doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @RaymondChen I see, but it still doesn't work with *SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME* privilege, *WRITE_OWNER* flag and *KEY_ALL_ACCESS* in the RegOpenKeyExW calls

Comment: `SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME` should not be passed into `RegOpenKeyExW` but used to modify the token of the process that calls `RegOpenKeyExW`. See the bottom section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-key-security-and-access-rights and then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm obviously not passing *SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME* directly into RegOpenKeyExW, I'm following standard practice and elevating current process token to the higher privilege.

Comment: `SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME` doesn't give you `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` access. it means that you are now allowed to call `SetNamedSecurityInfo` with `OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION`. And even then, owners get only `WRITE_DAC` access (not `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` access).